# Sequelize database update slow to save

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js, amazon-rds, sequelize-cli

I've been working with Sequelize for updating my database (3,250,000 rows). I am using it for updating individual rows in the database once at a time using the `.save()` method. We are awaiting on `.save()` to make the update synchronous (code won't continue until after `.save()` returns). Right after running `.save()` (under 50ms), I run a query to find that row. Once I get that row, I check to see if the content has been updated. To my surprise, my changes weren't being made.

If run `.save()`, have the system sleep for one second, and run the select for that row, the row is properly updated! My current thought process suggests that `.save()` is not a concrete confirmation that the database has accepted AND completed the row update. If that is the case, what would be a better alternative to `.save()` for properly updating the database via Sequelize?

Comment: Are you using the `UPDATE` statement to change 3M rows?  Sounds like a bad schema design.  Please provide the generated SQL so we can analyze it further.

Comment: No, we are changing 1 row of 3M rows. I am unable to share the schema with you. I am just wanting to know why the .save() method is returning when my database hasn't fully updated the row.

Comment: Sounds like there is not a suitable index.  Please provide the `UPDATE` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Or maybe you need a transaction to prevent other connections from seeing inconsistent data.  Done properly, MySQL _will_  "do the right thing".  I cannot guess what ".save" does; I need to see the SQL.

Comment: I understand - we need to see some code as if you are actually awaiting it, the promise is fulfilled when the DB has persisted the data; can you share some minimal code? Something must be going wrong somewhere - it should be a concrete confirmation.